# How To Define A Docusign Event/Envelope Notification Python API

Tags: django, python-3.x, docusignapi

For my company, I've been creating a webapp that will make the creation and signing of a letter of agency easier. I am almost completely finished with it. However, the only issue that I am experiencing is that, after the envelope is created, the email is never received by the recipient asking for the signature. I have checked under docusign's manage tab, and the envelope is listed there, with the correct recipient email address. I've attempted to resend it multiple times, and the email is still never received, although it's listed as being sent.

The code that I'm using is as follows:

```
username = "myDocusignUsername"
integrator_key = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"
redirect_uri = "http://myredirecturi"
private_key_filename = "path/to/pKey.txt"
user_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_user_id = 'recipient@gmail.com'

# Add a recipient to sign the document
signer = docusign.Signer()
signer.email = "recipient@gmail.com"
signer.name = "Recipient Name"
signer.recipient_id = '1'
signer.client_user_id = client_user_id

sign_here = docusign.SignHere()
sign_here.document_id = '1'
sign_here.recipient_id = '1'
sign_here.anchor_case_sensitive = 'true'
sign_here.anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left'
sign_here.anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false'
sign_here.anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'

sign_here.anchor_string = 'Signature of individual authorized to act on behalf of customer:'
sign_here.anchor_units = 'cms'
sign_here.anchor_x_offset = '0'
sign_here.anchor_y_offset = '0'
sign_here.tab_label = 'sign_here'
sign_here.IgnoreIfNotPresent = True;
tabs = docusign.Tabs()
tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]

# Create a signers list, attach tabs to signer, append signer to signers.
# Attach signers to recipients objects
signers = []
tabs = tabs
signer.tabs = tabs
signers.append(signer)
recipients = docusign.Recipients()
recipients.signers = signers

# Create an envelope to be signed
envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition()
envelope_definition.email_subject = 'Please Sign the Following Letter of Agency!'
envelope_definition.email_blurb = 'Please sign the following Letter of Agency (LOA) to complete the process!'

# Add a document to the envelope_definition
pdfpath = "path/to/mypdf.pdf"
with open(pdfpath, 'rb') as signfile:
    file_data = signfile.read()
    doc = docusign.Document()
    base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode('utf-8')
    doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
    doc.name = "Signed_pdf.pdf"
    doc.document_id = '1'
    envelope_definition.documents = [doc]
    signfile.close()
envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
envelope_definition.status = 'sent'

api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)

oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)
print("oauth_login_url:", oauth_login_url)
print("oauth_base_url:", oauth_base_url)

api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()

try: #login here via code
    login_info = auth_api.login()
    login_accounts = login_info.login_accounts
    base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
    api_client.host = base_url
    docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

    envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id, envelope_definition = envelope_definition)

    print(envelope_summary)
except ApiException as e:
    raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return HttpResponse({'sent'})
```

It might be worth noting that I have not defined an envelope notification, nor an event notification. I'm suspecting that this might be the reason that I'm not receiving the email. I've taken a look through the documentation, but I don't quite understand how to define either in Django (the python framework I am using). Is this a valid reason as to why my email is never being received? And, if so, would somebody be willing to help me in the right direction to creating those notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipients with a client_user_id defined are "Captive" or "Embedded" recipients. In a Captive workflow, you are telling DocuSign that you will handle recipient authentication and access to the envelope.

If you remove the client_user_id parameter, the recipient will be a standard "remote" recipient and the normal email workflow will proceed.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! :)